# salesforce email service / apex limit

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

Our order DB is trying to send to SF orders via e-mail service to customer object. Because of SF daily limits of 5,000 for our org and > 5,000 orders on some days, we adjusted the code to where we can get > 1 order in one e-mail.

The issue is that 1-10 orders within one e-mail work fine. If > 10, then no-joy. Can't find anywhere in the code where this would happen.

The code block is rather large, so here is a .txt to the file. ..this is the apex class associated with the e-mail service.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/rz5zbhf7q7yku0w/apex.txt

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Although I can't be specific without running your code, I'm inclined to think that you're hitting a governor limit, either

1) The limit on the number of queries run — you have a lot of SOQL queries inside the main loop

2) The total number of script statements executed — less likely but you are doing a lot of processing on fields etc..

I would run this code from execute anonymous providing it with dummy data, that way you should see an error message if you're hitting one of the above limits.

Comment: Thanks, ill try this and report back.

Comment: Also, as an oddity before testing the above. We can't seem to get the "bad number" of orders processed/created. It will sometimes create 50 records without an issue. While others, 15 might not take. It does seem that as the number of 1:many (email:orders) is sent with the email service, the less likely it will work. Again, will report back findings ...thanks.

Comment: It's like to be related to the number of child records involved, if it's not the main objects you're dealing with. Best bet is to turn on the debug logs for the appropriate user and see what's happening inside the service method, should give you some indiction of where things are coming to a halt.